# Best way to insert IList<Stream> m_streams; object in sql?

Tags: c#, sql, list

I have a list `IList<Stream> m_streams = new List<Stream>();`
i want to insert m_streams object to sql, so how this can be done and what kind of datatype should i use to store it and how can i get it again from sql database?

Comment: I have created a varbinary(max) field in sql and inserted this object in sql using convert(varbinary(max), obj) but when im trying to get it back using "m_streams = (List<Stream>)dt.Rows[0]["PrintStream"];" then it show an error "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte[]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.IO.Stream]'"

Comment: Do you want to store all data from stream, or only information about the stream: it's source, read position etc?

Comment: yes i want to store complete stream object.

Answer (score 0):

You should try binary serialization/deserialization. Maybe BinaryFormatter class will be helpful.

But I have a doubt it will work, because **Stream** is not a simple data-entity - it **is a wrapper over COM object** and I'm not sure it is possible to serialize/deserialize it in simple way. So **you'd rather save the location where the stream reads data from and position. And then create new stream object, based on this data.**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have no idea as to what is stored in the stream I would suggest using FILETABLE instead of a regular table. Otherwise your system will be very prone to errors regarding record size and encoding. Indexing will probably not be very useful in your table anyway.

As to whether serializing the Stream object itself is a good idea, I would say that you probably will not manage to do that. But streaming the content in and out would accomplish more or less the same thing. The properties of the stream object itself is not something that you would wish to persist, but the content is ofcourse interesting.